# Looping through multidimensional array with out knowing the association fields

Tags: php, multidimensional-array, foreach

I am populating a multidemensional array and I don't know what going into it, but I'm trying to access the data.  Basicly this is what I have.

```
while (some condition) {
     $data[] = $stuff;
}
```

Then I am trying to access it like this.

```
for ($i = 0; $i < count($data); $i++) {
     foreach ($data[$i] as $key => $value) {
          echo $key . " => " . $value;
     }
}
```

But it is not working, which is why I am here asking.

I have also tried storing `$data[$i]` into a temp array and looping it, but it fails as well.

Comment: Can you show us an example of the array?

Comment: Stuff is an array as it's passing 'is_array' check.  The main problem is I can't even get an example of the array, which is fustracting me.  I'm getting the information from a basic data base and trying to use it inside of php.  Doing some further inspection I am getting a timed out failure so it may not be the php code.  Which is mainly why I asked my question.  Knowing that this should work I can go back to some other people to see if they can fix thier side of it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
foreach ($data AS $datum) {
   if(is_array($datum)){
      foreach ($datum as $key => $value) {
           echo $key . " => " . $value;
      }
   }else{
       echo 'Sorry mate your $stuff is fcked up';
   }
}
```

Comment: This looks good!  I was just starting to think along this line of a nested for each.

Answer (score 0):

What do you mean "it is not working"? What errors are you getting? Have you tried the `var_dump` command to see if $data[$i] contains anything?

Basically if you have no idea what is in $stuff ... you need to do a lot more error and type checking. For example, if $data[$i] isn't an array, that foreach loop will likely fail. Think about using the `is_array` method.

Comment: So is the php code corret then for a multidemensional array? I'm interfacing with non php code and mining data, so I have not direct connection to the data I'm accessing. I just need verify that my php is correct before saying that the $stuff coming in is wrong. I'm new to php so I don't want to jump the gun too soon if what I got is right. I'm primarly a Java and C++ programmer. All I know about $stuff is that it is suppose to be an associative array like $array['name'] = ninja, being stored into my $data[].  I'll try using is_array to confirm.

Answer (score 0):

I'd probaby do it as

```
foreach ($data as $dkey=>$stuffs) 
  {
    foreach ($stuffs as $skey => $value) 
      {
        echo $dkey.' '.$skey . " => " . $value;      
      }
  }
```

and see what you get.

Comment: What @Surace wrote is probably a little better than mine because of the error checking.

Comment: True. This hopefully will tell me the deminsion location along with the key and value I'll give that a shot as well. Thanks! I'm trying Suraces now.

Answer (score 0):

Can you do it this way?

```
function show_data($data)
{
    if (is_array($data))
    {
        foreach($data as $key=>$value)
        {
            //do something
            show_data($value);
        }
    } else {
                // do something
        echo $data;
    }
}
```